# Reconstruct N-ary Tree from List

Tags: kotlin

```
data class Node(val ID : Long, val name : String)
```

I have an ordered list of the following three values (in order of appearance): ID, Name and Depth.

```
0000 : A : 0
0001 : B : 1
0002 : C : 2
0003 : D : 2
0004 : E : 1
0005 : F : 2
0006 : G : 1
0007 : H : 1
0008 : I : 2
```

Using this data set I wish to reconstruct the original *N*-ary tree as a `Map<Node, Set<Node>>`, visualized below:

```
A - B - C
      - D
  - E - F
  - G
  - H - I
```

What is the best (most performant and/or most readable) way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an `orderedList: List<Triple<Long, String, Int>>` you can iterate through the triples and keep track of the current parent at each depth so that you can rebuild the tree:

```
val tree = mutableMapOf<Node, MutableSet<Node>>()
val parents = ArrayDeque<Node>()
for ((id, name, depth) in orderedList) {
    val node = Node(id, name)
    // pop any parents from this deque as deep or deeper than this node
    while (parents.size > depth) parents.pop()
    // add node to tree
    tree[node] = mutableSetOf()
    // add node to parent's children if applicable
    tree[parents.peek()]?.add(node)
    // add node to parents stack
    parents.push(node)
}
```

And if you need to build `orderedList` from the string you have you can use the following (assuming the string is available as `input: String`):

```
val orderedList = input.trim().lines().map { line ->
    val components = line.split(" : ")
    val id = components.component1().toLong()
    val name = components.component2()
    val depth = components.component3().toInt()
    Triple(id, name, depth)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is to use stack to track parents on track from root to currently processed node:

```
        val input = """
0000 : A : 0
0001 : B : 1
0002 : C : 2
0003 : D : 2
0004 : E : 1
0005 : F : 2
0006 : G : 1
0007 : H : 1
0008 : I : 2
"""
        val parsedLines = input.split("\n")
                .map { it.trim() }
                .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                .map { line ->
                    val parsedLine = line
                            .split(":")
                            .map { it.trim() }

                    object {
                        val preOrderIndex = parsedLine[0].toInt()
                        val name = parsedLine[1]
                        val height = parsedLine[2].toInt()
                    }
                }
                .sortedBy { it.preOrderIndex }

        parsedLines.forEach { println("${it.preOrderIndex} ${it.name} ${it.height}") }

        val map = HashMap<Node,HashSet<Node>>()
        val parents = Stack<Node>()

        for (nodeDesc in parsedLines) {
            val newNode = Node(nodeDesc.preOrderIndex.toLong(), nodeDesc.name)
            map[newNode] = HashSet<Node>()

            while (parents.size > nodeDesc.height)
                parents.pop()

            if (!parents.empty()) {
                val tmp: HashSet<Node>? = map[parents.peek()]
                tmp!!.add(newNode)
            }

            parents.push(newNode)
        }

        println(map)
```